# Can the retina emit light?

Tags: eyes, light, optics

The retina is light sensor, which converts light to an electrical signal.  LEDs can both emit and receive light. Similarly, is it possible to apply electricity to retina to generate light?

Simply put, in theory, can humans emit electromagnetic waves from their eyes?

Comment: No. More importantly, if the retina was emitting light you'd almost certainly saturate the photoreceptors with the emitted light, making it impossible to see anything, so what's the point?

Comment: @user137 I just think if retina could emit em wave in the same manner as LED, It would emit longer wavelength, maybe infrared, so not the same wavelength it could absorb. And it could be possible if we could control and practice it tobe useful with electronics device. Or have some hypotheses about superpower like mind reading or telepathy

Comment: @user137 but The main point is I want to know mecanic of absorption and energy conversion of retina that is it the same as LED or not. If it is then we could grow organic LED with bioengineering

Comment: Close voter and skeptics: this is a great question. Ever heard of otoacoustic emissions?  Ever thought about the physics between photon absorption and relaxation generating fluorescence?

Comment: It is very interesting but it's making no attempt to understand the biology of the problem, I'm going to close vote but would retract/reopen if the user makes it more biologically focused.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to explicity seek understanding of the biological considerations.

Comment: Even if it were possible to make the photoreceptors emit light at some wavelength, I imagine the efficiency would be so low that getting any appreciable energy out would require a huge amount of energy in. Of course, everything emits photons when you get it hot enough.

Comment: LEDs do not absorb light; a photodiode does.

Comment: @user137 - first you guess any photo emittance would swamp the retina and then you guess the efficiency would be too low to occur anyway? Criticizing questions is OK, shooting at them randomly with unfounded arguments is not.

Comment: The two close reasons so far are *Primarily Opinion Based* and "off-topic because it needs to explicity seek understanding of the biological considerations." Addressing the first, how is it POB? It either happens or it doesn't. Addressing the second, it might be addressed in [this meta question](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/2961/5198). It seems that @user137 might benefit from seeking to understand biological considerations.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I retracted, but based on the way the question is written, it is asking if humans can emit light if electricity is applied to the retina. As I  don't think that there has been an experiment expressly that has been conducted to apply electricity to the human retina to the point at which it emits light, then an answer to that question would be opinion based, even if you are drawing on information based on the research that you have referenced; that the retina can absorb blue light and emit yellow light. You provided a really good answer, but is an answer to a different question.

Comment: I think either you or @Christiaan should consider an edit to the question to bring it in line with the answer. Given that autofluorescences is definitely a plausible phenomena for which there is evidence for.

Comment: Yes, you can grow organic LEDs @Thaina, that is entirely possible. You might as well call human fabrication of LEDs 'growing '  LEDs, but I think I see the actual question you were after...;) Cool thought.

Comment: @AMR - "You provided... an answer to a different question." Yes, I think you're right. Some is due to not knowing anything about LEDs, another to misinterpretation of *electricity* (I was thinking of electromagnetic waves). But the titular question remains, and that's what I answered. :-/ But I agree; it's not an answer that addresses the spirit of the question.

Comment: I still maintain that there is no attempt to illicit a *biological* answer, there is no evidence that the user has even considered the physical properties of the retina

Comment: The retina is already constantly emitting electromagnetic waves. It emits infrared light.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please allow me to start by saying I know nothing about LEDs, so my answer isn't going to address your analogy. I'm also going to keep it more simple.

> Can the retina emit light?

Yes. The retina is able to give off light in the form of fluorescence. Since fluorescence is the emission of light by a substance (granted that substance must first absorbed light or other electromagnetic radiation of a different wavelength.)

> “We can use autofluorescence emission to image the retina and see certain features of it,” said Dr. Sparrow, the Anthony Donn Professor of Ophthalmic Science in the departments of Ophthalmology, and Pathology & Cell Biology. ...Most objects in the environment are visible because they reflect, as opposed to emit, light. However, the retina—which exists within the eye’s back wall, known as the fundus—can generate its own fluorescence.

The cells of the deepest layer of the retina, called the retinal pigment epithelium (RPE), contain fluorescent compounds, which when excited by blue light emit a yellow fluorescence.

This ability changes with age, disease, etc.

> Excessive accumulation of lipofuscin granules in the lysosomal compartment of retinal pigment epithelium cells represents a common downstream pathogenetic pathway in various hereditary and complex retinal diseases, including age-related macular degeneration.

Lipofuscin is one of several fluorophores in the RPE. Different fluorophores may be related to different damage to the eye.

> A major hydrophobic component of RPE lipofuscin is the fluorophore A2E... Given that A2E strongly absorbs in the blue region of the spectrum, together with the known susceptibility of RPE to blue light damage, we undertook to investigate A2E as a fluorophore involved in blue light toxicity.

<sub>[Science Insight: Using the Retina’s Natural Fluorescent Light to Measure and Treat Disease](http://www.columbiaeye.org/about-us/news-and-events/science-insight-using-retina%E2%80%99s-natural-fluorescent-light-measure-and-treat)</sub>
<sub>[FUNDUS AUTOFLUORESCENCE IMAGING: Review and Perspectives](http://journals.lww.com/retinajournal/Abstract/2008/03000/FUNDUS_AUTOFLUORESCENCE_IMAGING__Review_and.2.aspx)</sub>
<sub>[The Lipofuscin Fluorophore A2E Mediates Blue Light–Induced Damage to Retinal Pigmented Epithelial Cells](http://iovs.arvojournals.org/Article.aspx?articleid=2123554)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the main point I mention LED is because it is photovoltaic, conversion between electricity and electromagnetic wave. The point is photovoltaic will absorb wave to generate electric current. And it is reversible material that if apply electric current it will emit light. So I wonder if the mechanic of light absorbtion to convert light energy to electric signal of retina is photovoltaic then it could reversible by retina material emit light when apply cirrent

Comment: Still your answer amaze me that retina is also fluorescence emitting yellow light. So maybe human always see blue light with a bit of yellow, never see true blue, or even any true color if other cell fluorescing other light too

Comment: @Thaina To specifically address the idea of using electricity to make photoreceptors "work in reverse" and emit light, we have to look at [how photoreceptors work.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_phototransduction) A photon hits a chemical in the receptor, causing it to absorb energy and change shape. This triggers a series of proteins to signal each other and eventually close sodium and calcium channels. With those channels closed, the cell becomes hyperpolarized. While this is described in terms of electric charge, it is not the same as semiconductors like LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

I think is an simple yet very applicable answer here.

*Anything with a temperature will emit photons via thermal radiation.*